# SVG: iframe renders outside of foreignObject

Tags: html, svg

I have an `iframe` inside a `foreignObject` inside a `g` inside a `svg`, like in the following code:

```
<svg width="1024" height="1024">
  <g transform="translate(240, 240)">
    <foreignObject width="300px" height="200px">
      <div
        style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background-color: blue;"
      />
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(240, 240)">
    <foreignObject width="300px" height="200px">
      <iframe
        width="300"
        height="200"
        src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html">
      </iframe>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I would expect the `iframe` to be rendered at the position specified by the parent `g`'s transform the same way the `div` is, but instead it renders at the origin of the page.

Here is the same code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/samuelmtimbo/pen/XoEzLj).

EDIT: I can see this happening on Chrome and Safari on Mac. It is working fine on Firefox.

How can I make the `iframe` render in the correct position?

Comment: Works for me on Firefox on Mac. Presumably your browser on your platform doesn't work, in which case report it to your browser's bugtracker unless it's a known issue in that bugtracker.

Comment: It doesn't work on Chrome Mac. However if I'm using a codepen iframe it works.

Comment: What is a codepen iframe? @enxaneta

Comment: When you open a pen, down right you have a button "Embed". This is giving you a code that is producing an iframe to embed in a web page.

Comment: I got the same issue did you find an answer